# How to transpose range in Excel through insertion of new lines?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

My data looks like this:

```
a 1 2 
b 1 2
c 1 2
```

I want to reorganise it so it looks like this:

```
a 1
a 2 
b 1
b 2
c 1
c 2
```

Comment: I suspect my question is downvoted because it is a duplicate. Would anyone be so kind as to point me in the right direction so I can delete?

Comment: More likely due to the fact that you didn't try anything yourself - this isn't a "question", it plainly is a request for someone to write a macro for you.

Answer (score 0):

*Please note that this is typed from memory, and NOT tested (I do not have access to Excel currently); you might need to THINK and adapt!*

**Recording a Macro:**

- Place the selection on the cell containing `a`
- Find 'Record a macro', close to it you see "Use relative references"; make the option be active.
- Start recording the macro.
- Select a shortcut key for the macro (e.g. SHIFT+CTRL+Q)
- Now do the actions required to move about the cells and their
  content, for the FIRST line *(keyboard use preferred!)*
- Make sure to END the recording with the cursor on top of `b`

From now on, the shortcut key repeats the same actions for the line the cursor is on.

---

**Additionally, how to modify the macro to repeat for non-empty lines:**

Alt+F8 shows a list of the available macros, where you can select to edit the macro you created above.

If you EDIT a cell WHILE recording the macro you will get a statement in the macro that reads similar to:

`ActiveCell.value="blabla"`

... this is easily changed into

`if ActiveCell.value<>"" then goto Repeat`

which of course belongs at the end of the macro code, just before "end sub".

Then add a line 
`Repeat:`
at the top, as a marker for where to restart for repeats
*(that is a "label", look it up in the help for "goto" if I goofed here)*.

If you have done the above correctly, the macro will repeat for all lines that has something in the cell where it "ends"

*Happy transposing!*